# How to model a curve with multiple shapes?

Tags: graphing-functions, curves, mathematical-modeling, nonlinear-system

I have the following conceptual model:

[image]

I want to be able to create an inferential model (e.g., NLM, GAMM, etc.) that can predict the above conceptual model.

To do so, I need my predictive model to account for the curves/structure of the conceptual model.

I don't know how to do that...

I'd seen elsewhere that the assymptotic part of the model could be graphed as $f(x) = b[1 - exp(ax)]$ , where $b$ is the asymptote and $a$ controls the rate of approach to the asymptote.

I also know a 3rd or 4th order polynomial might capture some of the oscillation behavior.

Can anyone help me construct a mathematical model that overlays my theoretical curves?

Theoretically, I want to capture i) the different ascent patterns, ii) the magnitude of the peak, iii) the magnitude of the subsequent dip, and iv) late-term rate of approaching an equilibrium.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at Second order LTI systems. Basically the functions of your graph can be modelled by a differential equation of second order, for which the solution looks like one of these three.

For instance the "long lag" one can be modelled by a function that is $y(t) = A\exp(-t/\tau)\sin(\omega_pt+\phi)$

It corresponds to the solution of an equation of the form $\omega_0^2y'' + 2\xi\omega_0y' + y = 0$ where $\Delta = 4\omega_0^2(\xi^2-1) <0$
In this case you can even calculate the overshoot of your signal with respect to the final value. The two other cases correspond to $\Delta = 0$ or $\Delta >0$.

There is a lot of resources on LTI models online so you'll find more precise info there.

Comment: Thanks! +1.  I'll start reading [here](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~sullivan/22files/2nd%20order04.pdf). Could you define/explain any of the variables you've listed (e.g., ξ, ω, etc.) -- or are these just constants??

Comment: Yes they are just constants. Basically their value will influence the form of the solution. $\xi$ is the damping ratio and $\omega_0$ is the natural pulsation. The damping is what influence the look of the oscillations (and their number). The higher it is, the lesser the oscillations.

Comment: If you take the function $y(t) = A\exp(-t/\tau)\sin(\omega_pt+\phi)$ for instance then $\frac{1}{\tau} = \xi$ and $\omega_p = \omega_0\sqrt{\xi^2 -1}$